# How can I detect a key pressed during a pause in python?

Tags: python

I made this code in python where after 5 seconds it will press the key 'a' every second, and if you press 'q' the program will end. The problem is that the program only tries to detect if 'q' is pressed after the 1 second is passed for a brief moment. How can I make so that if at any moment while the program is running I press 'q' the program ends?

```
import keyboard

import time

time.sleep(5)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.press_and_release('a')
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            print('Done!')
            break
```

Comment: You could possibly start another thread that would poll the keyboard for 'q'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [Matteo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12621642/matteo-fiorina) answer will do the job, you might still wait a small amount of time after you press `q` before the polling thread stops. That's because the polling thread waits one second before checking the `run` variable.

If you instead of a thread, use a `Process` from the `multiprocessing` module, you can terminate it as soon as the user presses `q` and avoid the extra wait time.

Here is an example:

```py
import keyboard
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def press_a_every_second():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.press_and_release('a')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    worker = Process(target=press_a_every_second)
    keyboard.add_hotkey('q', worker.terminate)
    worker.start()
    worker.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the function to read the q key in a different thread, then you use a global variable to stop the program.

```
import thread

run = True

def keyboard_input():
    global run
    keyboard.press_and_release('a')
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        run = False

thread.start_new_thread(keyboard_input)
while run:
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.press_and_release('a')
```